# How to query joins from multiple table using Flutter SupaseClient

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, supabase, supabase-database

This is my schema I am trying to fetch a list of events from the table along with the host info and the list of attendees by matching `events.host_id` with `user.user_id` and `events.event_id` with 'attendees.user_id`

###### Schema

```
user(user_id, name, email)
events(event_id,event_name, host_id) // host_id is the user_id of host
attendees(event_id,user_id)
```

Also, note that both columns of attendees are foreign keys associated with `events.event_id` and `user.user_id` respectively.

Here is what I have tried which works partially for me

```
final response = await _supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*, $user!inner(*)')
    .order(CREATED_AT_COLUMN, ascending: ascending)
    .execute();
```

This returns the following desired output (missing List of attendees)

[image]

This returns data from attendees with results from users and events nested in the `attendees` table.

```dart
final response = await _supabase
    .from(attendees)
    .select('*, $user!inner(*), $events!inner(*)')
    .execute();
```

[image]

Expected output

```
{
event_id,
..
..

host: {
   id: host_id,
   name: host_name
   ...
   },
attendees: [
  {id: user_idevent_id: event_id},
  {id: user_idevent_id: event_id}
  ...
  ]
}
```

So I have also tried

```
 final response = await _supabase
     .from(events)
     .select('*, $user!inner(*), $attendees!inner(*)')
     .execute();
```

My guess is perhaps the way my tables are structured is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table definition is perfect!

Your final query should look something like this:

```dart
await supabase
  .from('events')
  .select('*, host:users!event_host_fkey(*), attendees(*, users(*))');
```

The way I got the weird `users!event_host_fkey` thing in the middle was by looking at the error message of the following query:

```dart
try {
  await supabase
    .from('events')
    .select('*, host:users(*), attendees(*, users(*))');
} catch(error) {
  // read the error message here.
  print(error);
}
```

The `events` table and `users` table have two relationships right now, one through the `host_id` foreign key, and another though the `attendees` join table. Supabase knows this, and will ask you to provide additional information on which association to use for the query. Folllowing what the error message will give you the original query that I provided at the top! I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have already the answer for your case. So I'll write answer for general case for other users.

For example, you have two tables "users" and "clothes".

And you have in "users" column "clothe_id" as foreign key for column "id" in "clothes".

You can use this code to get tables.

```
final List data = await AppSupabase.client
        .from('users')
        .select('name, clothes!users_clothe_id_fkey!inner(*)')
        .eq('name', 'Admin');

// [{name: Admin, clothes: {id: 1, title: Costume, level: 4, ...}}]
```

Also you can filter, for example, by column "level" in "clothes":

```
final List data = await AppSupabase.client
        .from('users')
        .select('name, clothes!users_clothe_id_fkey!left(level)')
        .gte('clothes.level', 2);

//[{name: Jane, clothes: null}, {name: Admin, clothes: {level: 4}}] 


final newList = data
        .where((element) => element['clothes'] != null)
        .toList();

//[{name: Admin, clothes: {level: 4}}]
```